# How to change a cell's value using vba based off a list on another sheet in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

Please bear with me. I want to write an `if` Statement in `VBA` that looks at a list of values on one sheet and if those values are on the second sheet, then change the cell's value on the second sheet using `VBA` and formula.

I'll try to show a sample of what I have.

**Sheet1** Table:

`Part # | Supplier`

`Y67    | SupplierY`

**`X23    | SupplierX`**

`Z11    | SupplierZ`

**Sheet2** Table:

`Part # | Supplier  | Quantity 1 | Quantity 2`

`Y799    | SupplierY | 644541     | 332154`

**`X23    | SupplierX | 97845      | 399987`**

`Z555    | SupplierZ | 4454512    | 2237419`

Using these two table examples, I would like to know what `VBA` code I could write to be able to look at **Sheet1** Table and see if any of those Part Numbers are found in **Sheet2** Table. If they are found, then I would need the quantities changed using the formula `=(Cell Value/ 1000 / 500)`. In this example `X23` part number is found in **Sheet2** so the new quantities should be `0.196` and `0.800`.

I hope this is explained well enough. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) when you need to find things in a table or a range by row.

Comment: VLOOKUP would not be feasible for the activity that I am doing since I would only need this formula change for about 20 part  numbers out of the 300,000 cells that are in Table2. I don't want to add a formula or change any of the other cells beside the few found in Table1.

Comment: VLOOKUP would be considerably faster than stepping though every cell in a column and the more rows in the sheet, the faster it would be. I also recommend you add a column for a flag for the rows you find. You can use the value of the flag to conditionally format the cells, also to filter on to display just the rows you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

```
sRow1 = 1  'Starting row of data on sheet 1
iRow1 = 0
sCol1 = 1  'The column your part numbers are in on sheet 1
sht1 = "Sheet1"  'Whatever the sheet name is

sRow2 = 1  'Starting row of data on sheet 2
sCol2 = 1  'The column your part numbers are in on sheet 2
sht2 = "Sheet2"  'Again, whatever the sheet name is

Do Until IsEmpty(Sheets(sht1).cells(sRow1+iRow1), sCol1))
    'Loop through all parts on first sheet

    iRow2 = 0
    Do Until IsEmpty(sheets(sht2).cells(sRow2+iRow2, sCol2)) 
        if sheets(sht2).cells(sRow2+iRow2, sCol2) = Sheets(sht1).cells(sRow1+iRow1, sCol1) and _ 
        sheets(sht2).cells(sRow2+iRow2, sCol2+1) = Sheets(sht1).cells(sRow1+iRow1, sCol1+1) then
           'We have a matching part number & supplier

            partQty1 = sheets(sht2).cells(sRow2+iRow2, sCol2+2)
            partQty2 = sheets(sht2).cells(sRow2+iRow2, sCol2+3)

            Sheets(sht1).cells(sRow1+iRow1, sCol1+2) = partQty1/1000/500
            Sheets(sht1).cells(sRow1+iRow1, sCol1+3) = partQty2/1000/500
            exit do  'Exits the do loop in second sheet
        end if
        iRow2 = iRow2 + 1
    Loop
    iRow1 = iRow1 + 1
Loop
```

Comment: I have yet to try this but could you please add a line of code that highlights or colors the cell once it's changed, so I could see which cells changed? I have to search through 30,000 records so I won't be able to find them easily. Thanks.

Comment: there is something wrong with the code or format during `if sheets(sht2).cells(sRow2+iRow2, sCol2) = Sheets(sht1).cells(sRow1+iRow1), sCol1) and sheets(sht2).cells(sRow2+iRow2, sCol2+1) = Sheets(sht1).cells(sRow1+iRow1), sCol1+1) then  'We have a matching part number & supplier`. It's red and doesn't seem to be in the correct `If, then` format.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I had extra unwanted close brackets in that if statement and in the same lines as the partQty/1000/500 equation

Comment: In terms of looking for what is updated, we could do a few things to make it easier.(i)Add a datestamp to another column of the update time, you then do a filter on that column for update time
(ii)Copy the updated data to a separate sheet as well as Sheet1
(iii)Raise an update flag on Sheet1 and you filter by that flag.

All of which might be better than colouring, which can be done easily enough - have added edit for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, after fixing the brackets, this doesn't work. Currently, I have this code inside a macro after all the data is copy and pasted from other files and afterwards I am trying to change some of the values. I was testing one part number out and searching for that in Table2 to see if the QTY changed. So no errors but nothing happens. Also, if I put the code in a sub under Table2 sheet in VBA, I get an error there. I am not good at VBA in excel, is everything supposed to go in a sub like a macro or just put the code there without any Dims?

Comment: That shouldn't affect it I think - I'd normally run from a module inside the workbook rather than put the code in any specific sheet - but your approach shouldn't break it as its all qualified.

You can step through the lines with F8 for debug mode, and make each entry, a variable for checking in debugging i.e. aaa = sheets(sht2).cells(sRow2+iRow2, sCol2).

Double check your sCol1 & sCol2 are right, as if your addressing the wrong one, it'll just stop (=never really start) as its possibly empty.